# How do you get a dollar sign into a dejagnu "expect" file pattern?

Tags: tcl, dejagnu

I'm writing a thing for which the string `"$ 2 3#::6"` is valid input and I need to have a dejagnu test for it, something along the lines of

```
{"\"$ 2 3#::6\""    "0 3" }
```

but no combination of escapes or sets has worked.  In theory, the expect file is a tcl script, but none of tcl the backslash, curlies, and quote mechanisms I've tried have done it.  In the past things like using a set:

```
set vect "\[ .4 .5 .6 \]"
```

to get square brackets has worked:

```
{"\"3 + $vect\"" "3.4 3.5 3.6" }
```

but nothing similar with dollar signs works.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just blundered into the solution:

```
{"\"$ 2 3#::6\""    "0 3" }
```

with a space between the $ and the 2, works;

```
{"\"$2 3#::6\""    "0 3" }
```

without that space tries to interpret the $2 as a substitution.

As Emily Litella--for those of you old enough to remember Emily Litella--used to say, "Never mind..."

Comment: I don't know how dejagnu mangles things, but in Tcl itself you can just put backslashes before a `$` that you want to not be a variable substitution.

Comment: Tried that, and a bunch of other things like {$}, {$2}, and so on--I expect dejagnu is doing something wonky.